# Email attachments not showing in mdaemon webmail

Tags: google-chrome, email-attachments, webmail

I have a single user who can't see any email attachments when accessing MDaemon webmail through google chrome, which is the default browser here for other compatibility issues. The emails sitting his their inbox show that they have attachments on them but when opening the email and clicking on the drop down to show the links to the attachments it is blank.

I have checked they if they the forward an email from the attachments can be opened and they can, I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling chrome in case some setting in chrome had been changed. I have looked and look on forums and instructions online but can't find anyone who seems to have experienced the same issue.